# Different Values for RequestSource in Service/Commandline

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net, publish, cruisecontrol, build-server

I have a CruiseControl Project Setup with two different Triggers for a SVN Triggered Build and a nightly Build.

```
<triggers>
        <scheduleTrigger name="Nightly Build" time="23:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild"  randomOffSetInMinutesFromTime="20"  />
        <intervalTrigger name="Continuous Build" seconds="120" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" initialSeconds="15" />
    </triggers>
```

Depending on the Trigger I want to send an EMail with the Trigger Name in the subject and publish the Build to the trigger folder.

```
<buildpublisher>
            <sourceDir>SomeSourcePath\bin\Release</sourceDir>
            <dynamicValues>
                <replacementValue property="publishDir">
                    <format>\SomeDestinationPath\Buildserver\DMS3G_PRISM\{0}\Build</format>
                    <parameters>
                        <namedValue name="$CCNetRequestSource" value="BuildPublisher" />
                    </parameters>
                </replacementValue>
            </dynamicValues>
            <useLabelSubDirectory>false</useLabelSubDirectory>
        </buildpublisher>
```

When I run it by clickign on the CruiseControl.NET Commandline Application it publishs it to the Folder named "Continous Build"/"Nightly Build", but when I start the Service the name of the Folder is ALWAYS the **Name of the Server**.

Do you know any solution for this problem?

Thanks
Jonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, if the Build is triggered directly via the Web Interface the Trigger Name is always the name of the machine where the service runs.